# How can I view my notification history on github?

Tags: github

When I click on the [notifications page of github](https://github.com/notifications?all=1) I only see unread notifications. How can I go back through my history and view notifications from all time?

Comment: I am not on github (I use BitBucket) but the screenshot in the [blog post](https://github.com/blog/1204-notifications-stars) about notifications suggests that there is an "All Notifications" button. Does this help?

Comment: That's the page I linked to. It doesn't show all my notifications.